# $routeParams showing Url variable parameter

Tags: angularjs, routes, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying to use routeProvider to create a search page. Below I have something like so:

```
    }).when("/search/:value", {
        templateUrl: "app/views/search/search.html"
```

What I want to show in the url is not 
`/search/searchValue`
 but more like 
`/search/value=searchValue`

I am setting the location as so:

`$location.path('/search/').search({ value: $scope.filterValue }); where $scope.filterValue is the searchValue.`

When I use this, I'm not able to view my page due to the `:value`. How can i change the url to the one I want as in you have the routeParam show in the url link?

Thanks,

Comment: `.when("/search/?value"`

Comment: Would the location.search method be efficient to send searchValue to value?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient". How coud it be "not efficient"?

Comment: Yes, it should be. Have you tested it?

Comment: Try without chaining them,

$location.path('/search/');
$location.search({ value: $scope.filterValue });

Comment: Nope this didn't work. I had changed the path to 

` }).when("/search/?value", {
            templateUrl: "app/views/search/search.html"`

and           `$location.path('/search/');
          $location.search({ value: "hi" });` to try to get /search/value=hi but instead get an error. So I think it is my $location.search issue since I am able to go to page /search/value=hi

Comment: Additionally, If I use /search/value?=hi i get it correctly to show the page, but when I use $routeParams the childelement is {"": hi} not {value: hi}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was use /search/?. The value after the "?" was the parameter.